# How to retrieve HL7 message from OpenMRS database?

Tags: hl7, mirth, openmrs

I am trying to retrieve HL7 messages present in hl7_in_queue table in OpenMRS database using Mirth.

1. I am using OpenMRS standalone 2.0
2. The openmrs-standalone-runtime.properties file contains the following details:

---

```
tomcatport=8081
 module.allow_web_admin=true
 connection.url=jdbc:mysql:mxj://127.0.0.1:3317/openmrs?autoReconnect=true&sessionVariables=storage_engine=InnoDB&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-            8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&server.initialize-user=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&server.basedir=database&server.datadir=database/data&server.collation-    server=utf8_general_ci&server.character-set-server=utf8&server.max_allowed_packet=96M
 connection.username=openmrs
 auto_update_database=false
 application_data_directory=appdata
 connection.password=kXI4^ecvG8Vk

vm_arguments=-Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:NewSize=128m
```

---

3. I am trying to create a channel in mirth using the details available in the openmrs-standalone-runtime.properties file. I have attached the screenshot of the same.

But when I click on the `select`->`get tables` button in Mirth Connect Administrator I am getting an alert as follows:

> could not retrieve database metadata.Please ensure that your
> driver,url,username and password are correct.

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong or suggest how to retrieve the HL7 message from OpenMRS database using Mirth.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with Mirth Connect 3.11 (Java 8) and OpenMRS 2.11.0 (Java 8, mysql 5.7). But when I go deeper into the error message it shows the root error as below:

> JDBC: SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

I searched around within SO. The answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332909/why-can-java-not-connect-to-mysql-5-7-after-the-latest-jdk-update-and-how-should) solved my issue. Basically in Mirth channel settings of the Database reader, use this db connection string:

`jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<dbname>?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting with Permissions and Access. Test the openmrs connection by logging into mysql with the mysql client, then test access to the specific database. This shows on linux but the cli is the same for windows.

> bashprompt> mysql -u openmrs -p
>
> mysql> USE openmrs;
>
> mysql> select * from *atableinopenmrs*;

If you get results then this user has permission's. If not you will have to fix the user.

Other:

The default port for mysql is 3306, you have 3317, is this intentional?

> mysql -H 127.0.0.1:3317 -u openmrs -p

If no host you will get

> ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3317' (2)

Post any errors you get with mysql client here.