# Why can Java not connect to MySQL 5.7 after the latest JDK update and how should it be fixed? (ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol)

Tags: java, mysql, tls1.2

In the latest update to the JDK in April 2021 (`11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~18.04`) support for `TLSv1` and `TLSv1.1` was dropped, presumably because since March 2021 those versions are no longer supported. This is evident by the diff in the `java.security` file:

Before:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
    EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

After:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

which is also discussed in this SO post: [SSLHandShakeException No Appropriate Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205947/sslhandshakeexception-no-appropriate-protocol) . In that thread there are also more answers popping up the last few days since the updated JDK version.

After this update of the JDK, we received the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
```

with `c3p0`.

After switching to `hikari` we got a more meaningful error:

```
ERROR [2021-04-29 16:21:16,426] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
! javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
```

We're running on MySQL `5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`. Now in my understanding as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html), MySQL 5.7 supports TLSv1.2. Also when running `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tls_version';` we get `TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` which suggest that `TLSv1.2` is supported.

So then the question is, why don't the JDK and MySQL just agree on using `TLSv1.2` and what can we do about it, to make them communicate with `TLSv1.2`?

Note: I don't think changing the `java.security` file as suggested in the other thread is a good long term solution to this problem!

Comment: And what is the question now? How to make Java accept TLS 1.0 again or how to make MySQL use TLS 1.2? It's not really clear to me.

Comment: thanks for the hint, i rephrased the question to make it more clear. I think the goal should be to use TLSv1.2 as the way forward.

Comment: Try adding 'enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2' to MySQL connection string. This will enforce TLSV1.2 protocol for java's mysql connection and you wouldn't have to make any changes to java.security file.

Comment: Since Connector/J 8.0.28 enabledTLSProtocols has been renamed to tlsVersions. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Answer (score 132, accepted):

As @skelwa already commented you will need to add the `enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2` configuration property in the connection string to resolve your issue.

A complete connection string for [Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-connectors.html) could look like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<dbname>?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2
```

For [r2dbc](https://r2dbc.io/) you will need to use `tlsVersion=TLSv1.2` instead.

For **Connector/J v8.0.28** `enabledTLSProtocols` was renamed to `tlsVersions` (see [note](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html)). However, the original name remains as an alias.

---

The question that remains is:

**Why don't the JDK and MySQL just agree on using `TLSv1.2`?**

Although both parties do actually support TLSv1.2, the problem you were experiencing is introduced by the default behavior of Connector/J. For compatibility reasons Connector/J does not enable TLSv1.2 and higher by default. Therefore, one has to enable it explicitly.

See the following [note](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html):

> For Connector/J 8.0.18 and earlier when connecting to MySQL Community
> Server 5.6 and 5.7 using the JDBC API: Due to compatibility issues
> with MySQL Server compiled with yaSSL, Connector/J does not enable
> connections with TLSv1.2 and higher by default. When connecting to
> servers that restrict connections to use those higher TLS versions,
> enable them explicitly by setting the Connector/J connection property
> enabledTLSProtocols (e.g., set
> enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2).

---

**WARNING:** please be aware that <strike>solutions</strike> suggesting editing `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` inside of `jre/lib/security` pose a ***security risk*** to your application and changing anything there might have severe implications!
There are reasons why those protocols were disabled and one should not simply remove everything or even just parts from that list.

---

**Note:** if you want to get more low level insights from the JDK to debug your problem you can enable ssl debug logs by passing the following configuration to the java comand:

`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake`
or even
`-Djavax.net.debug=all`

In your case you will see something like:

```
...(HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:170)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:98)
    ...
```

Comment: thank you for the recommendation. just wanted to add to also try using the *latest recommended mysql connector j* for the software you're using. We were testing with mysql connector 5.1.42, so I just tried to use 5.1.48 and enabling TLS v1.2 in the jdbc url and it worked! Also used java options `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3` and in tomcat server.xml `sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3"`. Make sure you also read the mysql notes here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Comment: Just a notice, this works even for IntelliJ that was not able to connect to several mysql... unless i added the "?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2"

Answer (score 25):

I just added **useSSL=false** and it worked for me.

`jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<dbname>?useSSL=false`

I have JDK 8, MySQL 5.7 and mysql-connector-java lib with version 5.1.38

**This is useful when you want to execute quickly in local environment only (not recommended for staging/test/prod)**

Comment: In a DMZ it might be ok to have no encryption instead of weak encryption. In Production it usually is not ok.

Comment: Question title: "how should it be fixed? (ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol)"

Your answer: Disable SSL

Comment: This solved for me. I only used this option because I'm on local development environment.

Comment: What advantage does `useSSL=false` provide over `enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2` (accepted answer)? I don't see a benefit, while it makes it insecure as a downside?

Answer (score 5):

I faced this issue due to the older version of *mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar & OpenJDK 1.8* version, After Upgrading to the 5.1.49 version solved my issue

Answer (score 4):

I came here because I had the same issue, but unfortunately,

> jdbc:mysql://host:port/dbname?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2

didn't work for me because I'm using r2dbc. After a little bit of debugging I found out the name of the parameter must be `tlsVersion` instead, so you can use, for example:

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:mysql://host:port/dname?tlsVersion=TLSv1.2
```

Comment: This is also how it works after Connector/J 8.0.28, enabledTLSProtocols has been renamed to tlsVersions. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not a StreamSets issue. This is a compatibility issue between Java and the MySQL JDBC driver

Choose the most appropriate solution from below for your situation
**Solution #1**: Add "enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2" to JDBC connection string
Verify MySQL supports TLSv1.2

```
mysql> show variables like 'tls_version';
+---------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+---------------------+
| tls_version | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 |
+---------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Update JDBC connection string

```
jdbc:mysql://[hostname]:[port]/[databaseName]?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2
```

**Solution #2**: Enable TLSv1 and TLSv1.1
File: $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security
**Old configuration**:
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, 
DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
**New configuration**:
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, 
EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL

**Solution #3**: Upgrade the MySQL database
The TLS version is automatically selected by the JDBC driver depending on the database version.

TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 will be used for versions below: 8.0, 5.7.28, 5.6.46

**Additional Information**
A recent Java update, specifically Red Hat/CentOS, disables TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 by default for Java 8

The MySQL JDBC driver will attempt to use TLSv1 and/or TLSv1.1 if the MySQL database version is below one of the following: 8.0, 5.7.28, 5.6.46

Answer (score 0):

If possible, the better solution should be to upgrade to one of the following releases of Connector/J:

- 8.0.19, released on 2020-01-13, the [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-19.html) for which say:

> The allowable versions of TLS protocol used for connecting to the server, when no restrictions have been set using the connection properties enabledTLSProtocols, have been changed to:
>
> - TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, and TLSv1.3 for MySQL Community Servers 8.0, 5.7.28 and later, and 5.6.46 and later, and for all commercial versions of MySQL Servers.
> - TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 for all other versions of MySQL Servers.

or

- 5.1.49, released 2020-04-29, the [release notes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-5.1-relnotes-en/news-5-1-49.html) for which say:

> The allowable versions of TLS protocol used for connecting to the server, when no restrictions have been set using the connection properties enabledTLSProtocols, have been changed to:
>
> - TLSv1, TLSv1.1, and TLSv1.2 for MySQL Community Servers 8.0, 5.7.28 and later, and 5.6.46 and later, and for commercial versions of MySQL Server 5.6, 5.7, and 8.0.
> - TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 for all other versions of MySQL Servers.

If that's not possible, you could consider upgrading your MySQL servers to 8.0.x, which some older versions of Connector/J will use TLSv1.2 to where they won't enable it when connecting to 5.7.x.

If you can't upgrade either (yet), then changing enabledTLSProtocols would obviously be necessary.

Answer (score -6):

You can do the following steps:

1. Open java.security file. (It is under jre/lib/security folder)
2. Find the following line : `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`
3. Comment that complete line.

After this try running and it should work.

Or if you want only specific algorithm remove it from disabled list.

You can send it in config and comment that in java.security file

```
jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<dbname>?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2
```

Comment: Commenting out "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms" is catastrophically bad advice...  It's a bit like saying: the fastest way to get to work in the morning is to leave your car doors unlocked and the keys in the ignition.  Selectively removing items is only slightly less bad...

Comment: @paulsm4 that is true and not encouraged outside the local dev environment.

Comment: Remember: things you do in a dev environment often have a nasty habit of inadvertently leaking out to your upstream environments.  Best advice: "Just Say No" ;)