# Amazon mysql rds refusing to accept credentials after upgrade

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds

I have an old RDS database that was on 5.6_MySql_1.23.0, being used by a Java application running:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.47</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I've been refactoring old code, and part of that is upgrading from java 8 to 11. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332909/why-can-java-not-connect-to-mysql-5-7-after-the-latest-jdk-update-and-how-should) Java 11 doesn't support TLS=v1.0 & v1.1 anymore.

So I upgraded the cluster instance to 5.6_MySql_1.23.1 which does support TLS=v1.2 And I upgraded mysql connector to:

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.49</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Running  `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'tls_version';` seems to return a TLSv1.2 enabled cluster:

> TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2

However, since the upgrade my username and password are constantly getting rejected:

```sh
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'dba'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
    at medispan.foundation.dataaccess.providers.sql.SQLProvider.createProviderConnection(SQLProvider.java:227)
    at medispan.foundation.dataaccess.providers.sql.SQLProvider.createConnection(SQLProvider.java:205)
    at medispan.foundation.dataaccess.providers.sql.SQLProvider.openConnection(SQLProvider.java:841)
    at medispan.foundation.dataaccess.providers.sql.SQLProvider.executeForResults(SQLProvider.java:1489)
    at medispan.foundation.dataaccess.providers.sql.SQLDataAccessProvider.innerExecuteForCollection(SQLDataAccessProvider.java:515)
    ... 120 common frames omitted
```

Here's my JDBC string that worked in my java 8 service:

```
jdbc:mysql://test-aurora-sdt-c1-0.cpdk4xuooxvm.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306?user=[user]&password=[password]&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&sslca=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&serverTimezone=PST
```

Here's my updated url for all the errors I've had to fix with the mysql changes since the two versions:

```
jdbc:mysql://test-aurora-sdt-c1-0.cpdk4xuooxvm.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/dba?user=[user]&password=[password]&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2&sslca=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&serverTimezone=America/Los_Angeles
```

Did I miss a step database version migration to enable tls? Do I have to do something with my cert bundle that I'm just not aware of coming from a dynamo background?

Comment: check the garbnts in the data base for user `user`

Comment: @nbk Sorry, you'll have to forgive me since I'm a novice when it comes to mysql. What do you mean by garbnts?

Comment: user `user` can be connected to normally by anyone using a java 8 tool or service; if that's what you mean.

The service is running in prod quite nicely in java 8.

Comment: The authentication error appears to be a bad username/password, reported by the DB itself (rather than anything in Java or a TLS connection error). So I would first try to connect using the command-line `mysql` program.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then something went wrong with the upgrade. Start over.

Comment: If it _does_ work, I would incrementally convert my client code, to see what fails. Start with the Java 8 version, unmodified, _and make sure that you have all needed configuration files._ Then change the MySQL connector version in Maven. Then require TLS 1.2.

Comment: To be honest, I would probably start over with both database and codebase, making incremental changes and seeing what breaks.

Comment: Will do, I'll report back when I can with any findings.